# Geodesics without a metric

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

By definition, a geodesic is a mapping $\gamma: I = (0, 1)  \rightarrow M$ such that $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}(t)} \dot{\gamma}(t) = 0$.

Here we only need the connection. So, we do not need a metric to define a geodesic? Is such kind of geodesic useful?

Comment: I believe such a geodesic is commonly called affine geodesic.

Comment: Seems like having a non-metric connection, one can define a parallel transport and then geodesics. I am not en expert, you may check what is done with *Cartan connection*.

Comment: Yes, geodesics are used in affine geometry; a good example to think about is of a pseudo-Riemannian manifold. It does have connections, geodesics, but no compatible Riemannian metrics.